# Контрольная по Delphi

Tags: delphi

Нужно создать программу которая заменяет в строке малые буквы(строчные) на большие (прописные). Уровень 2. Из трех данных чисел выбрать наименьшее. Из трех данных чисел выбрать наибольшее. Уровень 3. Дано целое четырех значное число. Используя операции div и mod найти сумму его цифр. Дано целое четырех значное число. Используя операции div и mod  найти произведение его цифр. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: задания элементарные. можно было бы и самостоятельно подумать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

```
var
  SimpleString : string;

begin
  SimpleString := AnsiUpperCase('The Cat Sat On The MAT');
  ShowMessage(SimpleString);
end;
```

На выходе: THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT

---

2.

```
if x > y then  
   begin  
     if x > z then  
       showmessage('самое большое число: ' + IntToStr(x))
     else
       showmessage('самое большое число: ' + IntToStr(z));
   end
else
   if y > z then  
     showmessage('самое большое число: ' + IntToStr(y))
   else
     showmessage('самое большое число: ' + IntToStr(z)); 
end;
```

наименьшее число по аналогии

---

3.1

```
var
  s, n: integer;
begin
   S:=0;
   n:= 123;
   while N<>0 do begin
      S:=S+N mod 10;  
      N:=N div 10;
   end;

   showmessage(inttostr(s));
end;
```

---

3.2

```
var
  s, n: integer;
begin
   S:=1;
   n:= 123;
   while N<>0 do begin
      S:=S*(N mod 10);  
      N:=N div 10;
   end;

   showmessage(inttostr(s));
end;
```